# Reorder the features in a layer to display on infowindow

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to display features from results on infowindow, I have written the following code for that, But I am not getting the output.

Please suggest me where to modify in my code to get first type "CIT" and next type "CNY" on infowindow.

```
promises.then(function (results) {
                    //results are in same order as were passed to the all constructor
                    var showFeatures = [];
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        dojo.forEach(visibleLayers, function (layer, index) {
                            //set the info template for each returned feature   
                            dojo.forEach(results[index], function (result, fIndex) {

                                if (results[index].length>0) {                                  
                                        if(result.feature.layerId == 2){
                                            if (result.feature.attributes.munitype == "CNY"){
                                                result.feature = results[4].reverse();
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                result.feature = results[4];
                                            }

                                        }
                                        /*else{
                                        result = results[4];                                        
                                        }*/

                                        else {
                                            result.feature.infoTemplate = layer.infoTemplate;
                                            showFeatures.push(result.feature);                                  
                                        }

                                }

                            });
                        });

                        if (showFeatures.length > 0) {
                            app.mapUtil.map.infoWindow.setFeatures(showFeatures);
                            app.mapUtil.map.infoWindow.show(mapPoint);
                        }

                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    app.logger.logError("showInfoPopups Error searching for results", error);
                })
```